# Android 7+ problem to install apk through "pm install..." using Runtime.getRuntime().exec from system app

Tags: android, command-line-interface, system, android-permissions, android-sdk-tools

Im installed apk into /system/priv-app folder in my Android 7.1.1 emulator so it works as privilege system app but when when I try to install apk using this code of my app

```
val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
val process = runtime.exec("pm install -r -f $apkFilePath")
process.waitFor()
val output = process.inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
val error = process.errorStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
```

In the `error` output I'm getting

> Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial:
> runInstallCreate from pm command asks to run as user -1 but is calling
> from user 0; this requires
> android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

I tried to add permission in the Manifest file

```
  <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"
        android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"
        />
```

But still getting the same error. I even tried

```
runtime.exec("pm install -r -f --user -1 $apkFilePath")
```

still giving the same error

What is interesting if try this code

```
runtime.exec("pm install -r -f --user 0 $apkFilePath")
```

then the `error` output will become `NullPointerException`

So why `INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL` permission doesn't work and `--user -1` doesn't work as well? I thought system privilege app has access to install apk silently, so where is the problem then?

Comment: have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

found a way to resolve it on rooted device with system level app present in system/priv-app.
install app with as su like this.

```
val command = "pm install -r $pathToApk"

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf("su", "-c", command))
```